# Изменить SRC по клику / Переключить изображение по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть изображение `<img src="img.jpg" />`,
 нужно при клике на инпут
 `<input type="radio" value="Белый"/>` взять его значение и подставить в src , чтобы вышло вот так `<img src="img_белый.jpg" />` есть варианты как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой вариант на jQuery

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.radio', function() {
var $link = jQuery('.link');
var src = $link.data('src');
if (!src) {
src = $link.attr('src').slice(0,-4);
$link.data('src', src);
}
$link.attr('src', src + '_' + $(this).attr("value") + '.jpg');
console.log($link.attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="white" class='radio'/>
<input type="button" value="yellow" class='radio'/>
<input type="button" value="red"class='radio'/>

<img src="images/img1.jpg" class="link"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Довольно костыльно, но работает. Я сам еще учусь :)

```js
function myFunction(value){
  var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
  var startOfName = "img";//начало названия [img]_белый.jpg
  var previousImg=img.src.substring(img.src.lastIndexOf('/')+1,img.src.length).split(".");
  img.src = startOfName+"_"+value+"."+previousImg[1];
alert(img.src);
}
```

```html
<img src="img.jpg" id="myImg"/>
<input type="button" value="white" onClick="myFunction(this.value);" id='btn'/>
<input type="button" value="yellow" onClick="myFunction(this.value);" id='btn'/>
<input type="button" value="red" onClick="myFunction(this.value);" id='btn'/>
```

Comment: Да, работает)  только плохо что после каждого нажатия на кнопку значение дублируется

Comment: это можно исправить?

Comment: @SerhiyBilik просто тогда вместо изначального `img.src` берите фиксированное название (например, просто "img")

Comment: Могли бы вы вот [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/oqagpL9r/) поправить, а то у меня не получается

Comment: @SerhiyBilik вроде поправил

Comment: у меня по старом работает( обновите тогда ответ, чтобы я мог его принять

Comment: @SerhiyBilik странно, что на jsfiddle не сохранилось. Поменял

Comment: Работает , спасибо! подскажите еще как быть если у меня несколько инпутов с разными цветами? Заменил `getElementById` на  `getElementsByClassName`, но не работает

Comment: @SerhiyBilik еще раз исправил